# Install Xcode 4 and keep Xcode 3?

Tags: xcode, ios, ipad, xcode3to4

I've read many time that we can install Xcode 4 and keep Xcode 3.

BUT, i've also read that it was not possible with Xcode 4 GM.

Anyone have done this with success?

#### Update:

Ok, I have installed-it. (different folder)

But it always crash at start. (xcode encounter an internal logic error)

Someone have an idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's fairly easy to do. When running the installer, just change "Install location" to something other than `/Developer`

Comment: Geez, I wish I knew that beforehand... :) Anyway, isn't XCode 4 (and hence any details regarding the installation procedure) still considered Apple Confidential Information? ;)

Comment: @Toastor in that case: "This is how you install separate copies of XCode 3"

Answer (score 3):

You can install them both fine, simply choose separate directories. I have Xcode 3 installed into its vanilla location (/Developer) whereas Xcode 4 is in '/Developer/XCode4'.

To change the install location: On the 'Installation Type' screen within the installer you'll notice that the 'Developer' folder listed next to the top install item is actually a dropdown - click this then choose 'Other..' to select a custom location.

Comment: KomodoDave's instructions are actually relevant in the latest installer. This way of choosing an alternative install location is very non-standard, and I indeed overlooked it. The flagged answer could be out of date, as it suggests just hitting the "Change install location button", which gets you nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4 is still under NDA, but you can always choose to install Xcode 4 in another directory.