# How do I install XCode in a different location than the default?

Tags: iphone, xcode

For the life of me, I cannot figure this out. All the installer seems to let me do is choose between my two hard drives, and there is no option to select a directory on the hard drive.

I have seen the similar question here, but this doesn't help me: [Install Xcode 4 and keep Xcode 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009015/install-xcode-4-and-keep-xcode-3)

I just don't see a dropdown or option of any kind to change the installation directory.

Any help?

Comment: Try to rename folder `Developer` to `Developer_old` and then install new one xcode.

Comment: Make that `Developer-old` for consistency with the Xcode installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this post out. U can see here how to change the directory.. Hope it helps.

[Install Multiple xcodes](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/7/installing-multiple-xcode-versions.html)