# AppleScript data is not supported in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, applescript, xcode4.5, nib

I'm migrating a GUI-application from XCode 3 to XCode 4. The source-code is only AppleScript. When I'm opening the a NIB-file the following message pops up:

> AppleScript data is not supported in Xcode. The AppleScript data in this NIB file has been removed.

When I start the application its main-window just stays blank.

What can I do about this? I want to be able to edit my application, its GUI in XCode 4.5 and build it there.

Here's a screenshot of the message-box:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and copying the window in Xcode 3 and then paste it into the Xcode 4 project.

I have not tried this myself for this reason. But have done similar in the past.

I found the suggestion of using this method for this problem though [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/2012/May/msg00019.html)

Comment: How am I supposed to have XCode 3 and 4 on my Mac at the same time.

Comment: see here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009015/install-xcode-4-and-keep-xcode-3